# Jquery cookie + google map api 3 latlng

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript,

```
 if ( $.cookie("latlng") ) {
     myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $.cookie("latlng") ); //problem here??
 } else {
     $.cookie("latlng", "0,0", { path: '/' });
     myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
 }
```

The cookie function is using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.

My problem is that how do I pass the value of the cookie to google.maps.LatLng??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the information is stored in the cookie, but as far as I know, `google.maps.LatLng` requires *two* arguments, and it looks like you're only giving it one.

Try doing something like this:

```
if ($.cookie('latlng')) {
    myLatlng = $.cookie('latlng').split(',');
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLatlng[0], myLatlng[1]);
}
```